# Can two different matrices have the same eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume that we have two symmetric and non-negative matrices $A$ and $B$. They are not the same, even if they might look the same to the untrained eye. If I want to find the eigenvectors, I could use the $V$ matrix from the SVD

$$A = USV^T$$

where matrix $V$ holds the eigenvectors in its columns.

Are there any situations where the eigenvectors of $V$ from the $A$ matrix, can be the same as $V$ matrix from the $B$ matrix?

Comment: Eigenvectors from the SVD?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes

Comment: Why use the SVD instead of the eigendecomposition?

Comment: Re: "They are not the same, even if they might look the same to the untrained eye" Can you give any examples of matrices where it takes a trained eye to see their differences? Something like digits being written very small or in very bad handwriting??

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Because it's faster to compute with C-code. Less iterations.

Comment: Why are the singular vectors and the eigenvectors the same?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Because A is symmetric

Comment: @Heretic Are you sure?  What are the singular values of $-I$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes I'm sure. It's the same I guess?

Comment: @Heretic So, all singular values are $-1$, right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't know. You are the master here. I'm the one who asking questions.

Comment: @Heretic I never claimed to be a master.  Your question is nonsense and your attitude is not helping.  Since you are not paying anyone, you may want to adjust your attitude.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The whole reason why I'm asking this question is because I'm going to do SVD clustering and I wanted to know if different matrices for $A$ could results the same $V$ matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take as $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
 0& 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
 0& 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$. $A$ has eigenvalue $1$ and eigenvector

$v=\begin{bmatrix}
v_{1} \\v_{2}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\1
\end{bmatrix}$ which is also an eigenvector of $B$ and also the other eigenvector is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\0
\end{bmatrix}$.

Now $B$ has also eigenvalue $0$ and $B\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\0
\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\0
\end{bmatrix}$.

So $A,B$ are two non-negative symmetric different matrices which have the same eigenvectors! Therefore the answer is yes they can!!

Comment: It might be helpful to emphasize that these are different because the associated eigenvalues are different. Essentially, that you are choosing a different $S$ matrix.

Comment: Yes! It would not be possible with the same eigenvalues!

Comment: So Eigenvectors can be the same. Is it only with values on the diagonal who can be changed?